# mysql query choosing an incorrect execution plan

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, execution-plan, explain

I have a primary with an dependant subquery as a where condition that is choosing a wrong execution plan, and therefore is running for ever.

Main query:

```
SELECT  rtr.id AS id156_,
           rtr.procesada AS procesada156_,
           rtr.idTransaccion AS idTransa3_156_
FROM
   ReservasTiempoReal rtr 
        INNER JOIN Transacciones t ON t.id=rtr.idTransaccion
        INNER JOIN TransaccionLineas tl ON tl.idTransaccion = rtr.idTransaccion
        INNER JOIN Productos prod ON prod.id=tl.idProducto
        INNER JOIN Proveedores prov ON prov.id=prod.idProveedor
WHERE t.confirmada = 'S'
    AND t.codTipoTransaccion = 'RTRCT'
    AND t.fechaHora >= '2015-01-20 15:30:59'
    AND t.fechaHora <= '2015-01-21 15:30:59'
    AND prov.id=77        
       AND (EXISTS ( SELECT rtr2.id
                       FROM ReservasTiempoReal rtr2
                       INNER JOIN Transacciones t2 ON rtr2.idTransaccion = t2.id
                       WHERE t2.confirmada = 'S'
                                AND t2.codTipoTransaccion = 'ECTR'
                                AND t2.idTransaccionOriginal = rtr.idTransaccion));
```

And its execution plan:

[image]

In red is shown the used index using ‘codTipoTransaccion’ and ‘confirmada’ columns.
The first query (without the inner one) returns only 10 rows. But the whole transaction table has over 5 millon records. And most of them have the attribute confirmada = ‘S’.
If I delete the index ‘idxConfirmada’ (index by ‘confirmada’ field) the query takes only 10 seconds to execute and the execution plan is:

[image]

Just to add more info, if I execute the dependent inner query only with the records identified in the primary query, it returns only 6 records. The used query was:

```
SELECT rtr2.id
FROM ReservasTiempoReal rtr2
      INNER JOIN Transacciones t2 ON rtr2.idTransaccion = t2.id
WHERE t2.confirmada = 'S'
      AND t2.codTipoTransaccion = 'ECTR'
      AND t2.idTransaccionOriginal IN (14748319,
14748519,14750327,14751060,14751126,14751351,14751354,14752902,14754752,
14754785)
```

I don’t want to delete the ‘idxConfirmada’ index, I need the ORM to choose the correct plan. Also, I cannot use hints to ignore the index as the query is coming from hibernate.

How can I make mysql to choose the correct plan (not using idxConfirmada) ?

I am using MYSQL 5.1.51.

Added table details

```
CREATE TABLE `Transacciones` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `fechaHora` datetime NOT NULL ,
   `nroTicket` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   `puntosGenerados` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `creditoPendiente` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `debitoPendiente` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `saldoReal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `idTransaccionOriginal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `codTipoTransaccion` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `confirmada` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
   `nroLote` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `idMonedaImporteFinal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `totalImporteFinal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `anulada` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `idLote` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `online` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `manualConPIN` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `manualSinPIN` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facturada` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK2D546D5D771F9D3A` (`idTransaccionOriginal`),
   KEY `idxAnulada` (`anulada`),
   KEY `idxConfirmada` (`confirmada`),
   KEY `idxCodTipoTransaccion` (`codTipoTransaccion`),
   KEY `idxFechaHora_CodTipoTransaccion` (`fechaHora`,`codTipoTransaccion`),
   KEY `idxNroTicket` (`nroTicket`),
   KEY `idxNroLote` (`nroLote`),
   KEY `idxFechaHora` (`fechaHora`),
   KEY `idxOnline` (`online`),
   KEY `idxFacturada` (`facturada`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK2D546D5D771F9D3A` FOREIGN KEY (`idTransaccionOriginal`) REFERENCES `Transacciones` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15359563 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `ReservasTiempoReal` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `procesada` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
   `idTransaccion` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `idTransaccion` (`idTransaccion`),
   KEY `FK2375B195C078E769` (`idTransaccion`),
   KEY `idxProcesada` (`procesada`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK2375B195C078E769` FOREIGN KEY (`idTransaccion`) REFERENCES `Transacciones` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50805 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: The optimizer may not see the subquery correlation. Try replacing `WHERE t2.confirmada = 'S'` with `WHERE t2.confirmada = t.confirmada`.

Comment: 'confirmada' is not a key, is a Yes/No value. in this example it maches the primary query 'confirmada' field, but it also applies if I have confirmada = 'N' in the dependant query. In both cases, is using the idxConfirmada. Therefore, this change is not solving it. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: You also don't need `LEFT JOIN Transacciones t2 ON rtr2.idTransaccion = t2.id` -- an INNER JOIN will have the same result.

Comment: You may not have noticed, based on the boxes you drew, but the optimizer has actually swapped the order of the last 2 tables in the query plan.

Comment: As a last possibility, you can "disable" efficient usage of index for any column by comparing not its value but return of some function. For numerical columns simple "col+0 = X" is not going to use index on col in most cases, for string coalesce, or concat should be enough: "concat(t2.confirmada, '') = 'S'" - thats a good thing for testing but try to resolve it some other way (composite index mentioned in RJ's answer sounds really good)

Answer (score 3):

Use a composite index:

```
INDEX(confirmada, codTipoTransaccion, idTransaccionOriginal, idTransaccion)
```

The columns can be in any order, so I recommend shuffling them to meet other need(s) and/or facilitate removing some other index from `t2`.

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

**Edit**

For

```
JOIN ...    ON rtr2.idTransaccion = t2.id
WHERE t2.confirmada = 'S'
  AND t2.codTipoTransaccion = 'ECTR'
  AND t2.idTransaccionOriginal IN (14748319, 14748519, ...)
```

it is probably better to have this:

```
INDEX(codTipoTransaccion, confirmada, idTransaccionOriginal)
```

with `idTransaccionOriginal` deliberately last (because of the `IN`).

That should encourage the optimizer to start with `t2`.  I see that `idTransaccion` is an index in the other table, so the `JOIN` should be efficient.  (On a cold cache, there could still be a lot of I/O.)

Your `CREATE TABLE` multiple not-so-good indexes for the optimizer (not the ORM) to choose from.  What I am proposing should be a 'better' index that the optimizer will readily pick.  The optimizer looks at all the indexes, ignores any that are obviously useless (for the given query), and looks at statistics.  In some situations (perhaps not yours), the statistics are poor, leading to a poor choice of `INDEX`.  The "statistics" for one index is one number; it assumes a balanced distribution (which you point out is wrong for `confirmada='S'`).

Using a composite index (when it can be used) is almost always better than having shorter indexes.

(Unrelated) `DROP` the second of these, as being redundant:

```
 KEY `idxFechaHora_CodTipoTransaccion` (`fechaHora`,`codTipoTransaccion`),
 KEY `idxFechaHora`                    (`fechaHora`),
```

Also, my suggested index would make `KEY idxCodTipoTransaccion (codTipoTransaccion)` unnecessary.

[More discussion on indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: added table details as suggested. I just want the ORM to choose the correct index. Is not a matter of statistics ? Chosing the correct index 'primary with idTransaccion' (second explain plain) would result in only subquering for the given 10 records and matching by idTransaccion. The first explain plan, would result in scaning the whole table (as most of the transactions are confirmada = 'S') for each of the 10 rows in the primary query. Again, statistics are not having any participation here?

Comment: I made some edits.

Comment: @RickJames the column is `id`, not `idTransaction`.

Comment: Oops, that makes most of what I said irrelevant.  I'll fix it in a minute.

Comment: See if that makes more sense.